# Checking character length in ruby

Tags: ruby, string

I got stuck in another situation: our users enter a text to be stored in a variable. The condition for that text is it can be allowed to enter only 25 characters, Now I have to write a regular expression which will check the condition, kindly help me out in this.

Comment: you don't need a regular expression for this. Try s.length

Comment: I know this is an old question, but if anyone arrives here I'd encourage them to read the documentation for Ruby's string class. Both `#length` and `#size` appear in the documentation.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

I think you could just use the String#length method...

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-length

Example:

```
text = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.'
puts text.length > 25 ? 'Too many characters' : 'Accepted'
```

Answer (score 24):

Ruby provides a built-in function for checking the length of a string. Say it's called `s`:

```
if s.length <= 25
  # We're OK
else
  # Too long
end
```

Answer (score 8):

Instead of using a regular expression, just check if string.length > 25

Answer (score 1):

You could take any of the answers above that use the string.length method and replace it with string.size.

They both work the same way.

```
if string.size <= 25
  puts "No problem here!"
else
  puts "Sorry too long!"
end
```

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-size

Answer (score 0):

Verification, do not forget the to_s

```
 def nottolonng?(value)
   if value.to_s.length <=8
     return true
   else
     return false
   end
  end
```